# Where is todotxt-cli installed?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-mate

As title mentions, I want to start using it but have no idea where it is installed, I tried `which todotxt-cli` and `whereis todotxt-cli` but it says it doesn't recognise the package. Yet when I do `apt-cache policy todotxt-cli`, it tells me it's installed.

Missed out an important point, I installed it through the command line

```
sudo apt install todotxt-cli
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file list for `todotxt-cli` at http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/todotxt-cli/filelist includes `/usr/bin/todo-txt`, therefore you should run `todo-txt` in the terminal instead.

Answer (score 2):

`todotxt-cli` contains the program `/usr/bin/todo-txt` so you can use the command

```
todo-txt
```

See [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/todotxt-cli/filelist) for the full list of the package.

Comment: +1 indeed, and to answer the question directly, `which todo-txt` returns `/usr/bin/todo-txt` so... that's where it is, unsurprisingly

Answer (score -1):

To obtain the `todo.sh` file you need to go to `todotxt.com`.  Download the tar file and extract it to `/directory/location/desired`, `/home/user` would probably work best. Then follow the setup instructions found here [Quick Start Guide](http:////https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Comment: Why is this needed? The link is broken also...